Trying to use preg_match for single word or no spaces, to combat spam
I have a form I continue to build on, so that I can keep spam from being sent through.  So far, pretty good - in that the only thing now still getting through are single groups of random letters.  I have code that kills a send if there are three or more multiple capitals, but would prefer code that either dies on only one nonsense word OR dies if there is no space between at least three words.
This stops the send if there are 3 or more capitals in a row in my Comments:
if(preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}\w+/m',$comments)) {
    $error_message .= "Weird CAPs in the Message.<br />";
  }

I guess my problem is I know how to "sort of" write inclusive statements (if X is true) but don't know how to do exclusions.  Two different examples for instance; if there is only one series of letters entered in the form OR if there is no space between instances of letters, throw an error.
The spam I still get is usually like this: "gfgfdgfRTvdfwsvGFDgfd" - one nonsense bunch. Of course with my luck someone will need to use a 3 cap letter name... USA or STP or NRA.
The spam shows/comes into the Name field and/or the Comments field.
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email_from = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
  $comments = $_POST['comments'];  $error_message = "";

            
           $error_message = "";
if(preg_match('/http|www|audience|been seen before|bitcoin|business need|can I trust|completely new|content|create|dear friend|debt|dedicated team|design|developer|domain name|ensure|exciting|explosive|financial|first page|free money|free SEO|for free|fund|golden|help grow|here to help|hi there|honey|imagine having|increase your|instant|introduce you|landscape|leaverage|lifetime|loan|marketing|no oblig|pay off|personalized|porn|promote your|prove|rank on|return on their|SEO |sexy|staggering|subscribers|tax credit|team |to learn|top-|trusted|in charge|uncover|unparalleled|viagra|viewers|we guaran|working capital|you tired/i',$comments)) {
    $error_message .= "There are spammy words in the Message.<br />";
  }


if(preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}\w+/m',$comments)) {
    $error_message .= "Weird CAPs in the Message.<br />";
  }


if(preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}\w+/m',$name)) {
    $error_message .= "Too many capitals in the Name.<br />";
  }


if(preg_match('/http|www/i',$name)) {
    $error_message .= "No Spam.<br />";
  }


if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10,}$/', $telephone)) {
    $error_message .= "Phone requires 10 numbers.<br />";
}



if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

Hope I am clear - thanks.

Is this right? You are trying to stop people SENDING spam from a form on your site. Sounds like you have written yourself an Open Relay.

Now, my php throws an error so the form does not get mailed IF a match is detected.  So a spammer-bot fills in my form with 3 caps in a row and nothing gets sent (in my existing example).  I would prefer the error occurred because its only one word OR there is no space between at least 2 words.  Should be a better solution.

So basically you have written a very poor form and script. Show the whole script so we can suggest some fixes

As I said, as of now the only bots getting through are just throwing random letters into the two fields.  Happens about twice a week.

Why don't you add protect mechanisms like tokens or captcha?

Though I have been writing codes a long time, I am not proficient at this anymore.  Supposed to be retired.  Nor do I find for my minimal use that users will take the time to do Captcha - at least on my sites.  Blocking the php bot-hijacking with preg_match seems to be working.  I do take time to study other cases but have not seen an exclusion usage; only a matching/inclusive usage for preg_match.  Again, I am old.

this?  ^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$

I suppose you don't have logged in user, either, right? Everyone is just anonymous?

its an inquiry form for the public.  Name, email, phone, message.

How does gfgfdgfRTvdfwsvGFDgfd get through? It should fail the "weird caps" check.

BTW, the m modified is not needed in that regexp. It affects how ^ and $ are treated, so has no effect if the regexp doesn't have either of them.

Barmar - no it does fail (which is good).  I ended up piping this which limits the caps AND requires a space such as more than one word:  ^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$|[A-Z]{3}\w+  .
